# MVC5 templates not available in VS2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find the mvc5 templates for a new project. Others have asked the question but the answers keep saying we are selecting wrong options. That's not it. ..

I started with File> New> Project> 
then
 Templates> Visual C# > Web 
 then Select Asp.Net Web Application

click Ok 
and the next screen only shows Empty, Web Forms and Azure Mobile Service

I also selected .Net Framework 4.51?

How can I get the mvc5 templates to show up? I don't think my VS2013 is corrupted either.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096746/how-to-add-mvc5-to-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Trying to state the question clearly since most of the answers provided are related to users selecting wrong options which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, MVC5 is not installed in your computer.