# MVC5 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

[image]

I wanted to create MVC5 web application but I am unable to find the option. Should I have to install something? I am using visual studio 2013 professional version. I followed this [How to add MVC5 to Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096746/how-to-add-mvc5-to-visual-studio-2013) But I could not find the option mentioned in that stackoverflow link.

**File->New project-> web-> Asp.net web application** not found instead I have only the list of templates shown in the image.

Comment: you're looking in 'Visual Studio 2012' section... what is in Web (the level above the one you're looking in) - there should be ASP.Net web application?

Comment: The answer in the link you posted says clearly, and I quote: "Make sure not to select the C# > Web > Visual Studio 2012 sub folder". So, as @Alex pointed, go one level above and you will find it.

Comment: @Alex Thank you I  went to the sub-section of web instead of clicking web.

Answer (score 2):

Look in here, instead of the Visual Studio 2012 element

[image]

You should then see something like this

[image]