# ASP.NET Web template missing in visual studio 2013 solution?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make an asp.net mvc project but there is no tab of 'web' it is i followed newProject->visual c#->  but there is no web tab... help!!

Comment: What version of .net framework do you target? You have to select at least 4.5

Comment: i have installed 4.6.2

Comment: do we have to add .net framework to vs??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096746/how-to-add-mvc5-to-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Perhaps you should include a screenshot in your question.

Comment: i dont have reputation to post it

Answer (score 2):

Please go to the store folder of those templates like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates and check the existing of the templates, then use the following command to restore the default templates in VS.

please see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116(v=vs.100).aspx

Open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the below command as administrator:

> devenv /installvstemplates

In Between, you can go to the Control Panel/Programs and Features and right-click the VS 2013 item and choose change-modify, check or re-check the option ‘Microsoft Web Developer Tools’ like below screenshot.

[image]

After that, reopen VS and see if the web template appears or not.

Please let me know, If the issue still persists.

Comment: By clicking on change it just gives the option of repair and uninstall

Comment: You should see "Add/Remove Features"(Something like that) option too ! Can you please post a screenshot here?

Comment: Did you check in \ProjectTemplates folder if you got template or not?

Comment: Please open VS and check it. You should have web template option !!